# How to set click listener for button in listview in Fragment onCreateView()

Tags: android

I have a fragment with listview.I am populating lisview with list item which has textviews and a imagebutton.I want to set onClickListener on listitem button in fragment's onCreateView().I am populating the list using a Cursoradapter and list_item.xml.But I couldnot get a reference to this button in onCreateView() as button is not a part of inflated layout but a part of list_item.xml .How can I set click listener on listitem button.Any help is appreciated. 
Here is my fragment:

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_account, container, false);
 accountListView = (ListView)rootView. findViewById(R.id.list);
    mCursorAdapter = new accountCursorAdapter(getActivity(), null);
        accountListView.setAdapter(mCursorAdapter);

// I want to set click listener on button here.Button is in list_item.xml
```

// which inflates my cursoradapter.

```
   return rootView;
    }
```

My adapter class:
public class accountCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
```

public accountCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c);

```
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Inflate a list item view using the layout specified in list_item.xml
    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, final Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    // Find individual views that we want to modify in the list item layout
    TextView nameTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);

    ImageButton image = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.account_menu);

    int nameColumnIndex =  cursor.getColumnIndex(accountContract.accountEntry.COLUMN_NAME);

    String name = cursor.getString(nameColumnIndex);

    nameTextView.setText(name);

    int position;
    position=cursor.getPosition();
    image.setTag(position);
}
```

}

Comment: you have to register the clicklistener inside your accountCursorAdapter class, put your class in the question

Comment: Also, I suggest you to give a chance to RecyclerView :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could register your onClickListener inside your adapter:

```
  @Override
    public void bindView(View view, final Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        // Find individual views that we want to modify in the list item layout
        TextView nameTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);

    ImageButton image = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.account_menu);

    int nameColumnIndex =  
    cursor.getColumnIndex(accountContract.accountEntry.COLUMN_NAME);

    String name = cursor.getString(nameColumnIndex);

    nameTextView.setText(name);

    int position;
    position=cursor.getPosition();
    image.setTag(position);

    image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v)
      {
        //do something
      } 
    });
}
```

Comment: I have to set onClick in fragment as on button click I am showing a menu and users can perform various actions which requires fragment and sqlite table specific information.

Comment: Is there a way like findViewById to get the view of the button in fragment

Comment: no because your button is in your adapter, you can use Interfaces to get the value in your fragment

Comment: OK.Thank you very much .I will give your suggestion a try will let you know .